# Can't resolve big spaces between GridView images

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am having an issue with setting up a GridView full of images.

When the images are displayed, they have huge gaps in between them. I have looked up and tried many solutions but still can't seem to find a fix.

What it looks like:

[image]

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    style="@style/PhotoGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_thumbnail_size"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private String[] mStrings = {
        "www.URLs.jpg" };
}
```

LazyAdapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
    return vi;
}
}
```

Item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/img" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your lazyadapter?

Comment: Post your `item.xml` code, the culprit is that one

Comment: just remove `android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_thumbnail_size"`

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861606/how-to-set-an-android-gridview-with-different-column-sizes

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:columnWidth="80dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:numColumns="3"
android:stackFromBottom="false"
android:stretchMode="none" >
```

OR

android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"

OR

in adapter try this

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/galler_imageview"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    </LinearLayout>

<GridView android:id="@+id/PhoneImageGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center"
         />
```

Comment: I get the error on "</LinearLayout><GridView" stating "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    </LinearLayout>

<GridView android:id="@+id/PhoneImageGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center"
         />
```

### item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/img" />

</LinearLayout>
```